# How to fill color along the edge within specific distance

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I’m trying to fill color along the edge but I got stuck. 
First, I have an image and I apply the `sobel` filter on it. After I calculate the gradient, I get an edge `2d` array which contains the direction.
And now, I have no idea how to draw it.
The very first method that comes up to my mind is that I can check every pixel to see whether it’s on the edge and if yes then just make an intersection between the edge array and a circle(whose center is exactly that point), and run flood fill algorithm.
Here comes the problem, I don’t know how to intersect two-pixel array.

And the effect I want to get is like the image below.

[the polygon represent the edge array and the red part is where I want to paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul7Zg.png)

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

See this draw, use morphological operation with disk structure element and masking: [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9loBw.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally got through it by another approach. This question is just a part of my whole function. In fact, I was trying to crop the manuscript part from pictures. btw, I used adaptive gaussian thresholding to make it.